# Can I promote a column from plain text to rich text?

Tags: list, column, rich-text

If I have an existing list with a multiple-lines-of-text column, with data, can I promote that column to be rich text?

I had a look in powershell and see that there's a richtext = false flag but it seems to be read only :(

At the moment I'm trying to do it for MOSS but 2010 solutions would be welcome also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SP2010 or SP2007, If the column is of type *Multiple lines of text* I don't see any issue in editing the column and set the "*Specify the type of text to allow*" to Rich text

Comment: Didn't have the publishing feature installed.